# How to append child component into parent component conditionally?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have two components, parent and register component.

ParentComponent.html looks like:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="signup" (click)="getChild()">
        <register></register>  --//register component
    </div>
 </div>
```

register.component.ts looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: '../templates/register.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit { 
   ngOnInit() {
       this.registerService.getRoleList()
        .subscribe(res => {
            if(res.data){
                this.instRoleList = res.data.roleList;
            }
        });

     /* ngOnInit calls a service from which data is received and certain 
        conditions are met. I want this service to go only when getDetails() is called and <register> should get append to <div id="signup>

*/
   }
}
```

register.html code snippet looks like: ( it depends on the data received from register service data "")

```
<div class="form-group group" *ngIf="instRoleList">
 </div>
```

So, I want that on click of getChild(), register component gets appended to `<div id="signup">`

How to achieve this?

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="signup" (click)="getChild()">
          <!-- register component to append here on getChild() click -->
</div>
```

I have already used below code but didn't work.

```
$('#signup').append('<register></register>')
```

Comment: `*ngIf` sound like what youre looking for.

Comment: a simple boolean flag would probably do? something like: `<register *ngIf="some condition"></register>`

Comment: stop thinking in jQuery if you want to use angular -_-!

Comment: You can even do this with routing using the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and some more code

Comment: But I also don't want the service to be called that is in ngOnInit() in register.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be archieved with the ngIf directive:

```
<div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="signin">
            <!-- other code -->
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="signup" (click)="getChild()">
            <register *ngIf="condition"></register>  --//register component
        </div>
     </div>

@Component({
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: '../templates/register.html'
})
export class ParentComponent { 
   condition: boolean = false;
   getChild(){
      this.condition = !this.condition;
   }
}
```

This click event will work as a toggle function with this approach.

Comment: Register component contains a service call on ngOnInit() if it is placed like below, then that call would go.

 <div class="tab-pane" id="signup" (click)="getChild()">
           <register *ngIf="condition"></register>  --//register component
  </div>

I want that if I click getDetails(), then register component should append that div and only then that service call should go.

Comment: Then reformulate your question, you dont talk about any "getDetails" in it ;)

Comment: Ques. Edited. Kindly have a look